# Doing vlookup-like things on Python with multiple lookup values

Tags: python, dataframe

Many of us know that the syntax for a Vlookup function on Excel is as follows:

```
=vlookup([lookup value], [lookup table/range], [column selected], [approximate/exact match (optional)])
```

I want to do something on Python with a lookup table (in dataframe form) that looks something like this:

```
Name        Date of Birth         ID#
Jack        1/1/2003              0
Ryan        1/8/2003              1
Bob         12/2/2002             2
Jack        3/9/2003              3
```

...and so on. Note how the two Jacks are assigned different ID numbers because they are born on different dates.

Say I have something like a gradebook (again, in dataframe form) that looks like this:

```
Name        Date of Birth         Test 1         Test 2
Jack        1/1/2003              89             91
Ryan        1/8/2003              92             88
Jack        3/9/2003              93             79
Bob         12/2/2002             80             84
...
```

How do I make it so that the result looks like this?

```
ID# Name        Date of Birth         Test 1         Test 2
0   Jack        1/1/2003              89             91
3   Ryan        1/8/2003              92             88
1   Jack        3/9/2003              93             79
2   Bob         12/2/2002             80             84
...
```

It seems to me that the "lookup value" would involve multiple columns of data ('Name' and 'Date of Birth'). I kind of know how to do this in Excel, but how do I do it in Python?

Comment: Not just Python, but `pandas` it appears? Have you tried anything yourself? Looked at `.join()`?

Comment: Turned out pd.merge did it.

Comment: You can either close/remove the question, or post an answer and accept it, since you apparently no longer need one?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I can just do

```
pd.merge([lookup value], [lookup table], on = ['Name', 'Date of Birth']
```

which produces

```
Name        Date of Birth         Test 1         Test 2    ID#
Jack        1/1/2003              89             91        0
Ryan        1/8/2003              92             88        3
Jack        3/9/2003              93             79        1
Bob         12/2/2002             80             84        2
...
```

Then everything needed is to move the last column to the front.